# Вставка значения из другой таблицы. JOIN в рамках UPDATE.

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица table_1

```
|   А   |    B    |   C   |
-------------------------
|   1   |  'one'  | null  |
|   2   |  'two'  | null  |
|   3   | 'three' | null  |
```

Есть таблица table_2

```
|  COL_1  |    COL_2   |
|  'one'  |  'Arrrr!'  |
| 'three' | 'Caramba!' |
```

Нужно проапдейтить table_1 значениями из table_2. Или даже воспользоваться какой-то функцией. Выборка была бы такой:

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, some_func(t2.COL_2) AS C
FROM table_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.B=t2.COL_1
```

Но мне нужна модификация именнь первой таблицы

```
|   А   |    B    |     C      |
--------------------------------
|   1   |  'one'  |  'Arrrr!'  |
|   2   |  'two'  |    null    |
|   3   | 'three' | 'Caramba!' |
```

Как это сделать? Как джойнить в модификации значений? Получалось сделать в цикле на plsql для каждой строки вызывая UPDATE, но слишком медленно выходит...

Comment: А почему вы merge не попробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть `MERGE`:

```
merge into table_1 t1
using table_2 t2 on (t1.B = t2.COL_1)
 when matched then update
  set t1.C = t2.COL_2;
```

Еще `MERGE` может инсертить ненайденные строки, подробнее см. [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606).

Comment: Спасибо, никогда не приходилось пользоваться MERGE.

Comment: *если нет альтернатив* Да есть, как не быть... Oracle ещё пока поддерживает [UPDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708). Будет нечто типа `UPDATE table1 t1 SET с = (SELECT col_2 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.b = t2.col_1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Если такой апдейт посредствам SQL медленный, то попробуйте добавить индексы

```
UPDATE table_1 SET c = table_2.COL_2 FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.COL_1 = table_1.B
```

Comment: К сожалению выдаст ошибку. Пробуйте предлогаемое решение перед тем, как дать ответ.

Comment: Хм, где ошибка?